# PHP - using XPATH to reference XML element with 2 attributes

Tags: php, xml, xpath, xml-attribute

I am using XPATH (with PHP) to retrieve XML data based on the XML attributes. The XML structure is like this:

```
<products>
<product category="Desktop">
<name> Dell Desktop (d)</name>
<price>499.99</price>
<shipping cost="10.99" carrier="UPS" />
</product>
</products>
```

This code works fine, as it tests the XML element `<product>` which only has ONE attribute - named "category".

```
$productVar = "Desktop";
$x_path = $XMLproducts->xpath("/products/product[@category='$productVar']");
foreach($x_path as $Product) {
echo $Product->name . " - " . $Product->price . "<br>";
}
```

But the next two foreach loops are NOT displaying anything. They test the XML element `<shipping>` which has TWO attributes - "cost" and "carrier".

```
$shippingCarrier = "UPS";
$xpath = $XMLproducts->xpath("/products/shipping[@carrier='$shippingCarrier']");
foreach($xpath as $Product) {
echo $Product->name . " - " . $Product->price . "<br>";
}

$shippingCost = "UPS";
$xpath = $XMLproducts->xpath("/products/shipping[@cost='$shippingCost']");
foreach($xpath as $Product) {
echo $Product->name . " - " . $Product->price . "<br>";
}
```

Any advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `xpath`-expressions, you need to select `<product>` and keep the condition in `[]`:

```
/products/product[shipping/@carrier='$shippingCarrier']
```

and...

```
/products/product[shipping/@cost='$shippingCost']
```

Moreover, you need to set your `$shippingCost`to `"10.99"` instead of `"UPS"` to select data.

see it working: https://eval.in/128925

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
/products/product/shipping[@carrier='$shippingCarrier']
```

because `shipping` is not a direct child of `products`.

You could also look for all descendants like this:

```
/products//shipping[@carrier='$shippingCarrier']
```

Comment: Thanks. The coding you provided is correct! However, for some odd reason, in the echo statement in the foreach loop,                     .... echo $Product->name . " - " . $Product->price . "<br>"; .....            the only thing that is displaying is the hyphen.